# cannot enable system sharing on ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, connection-sharing

Enter system settings > sharing

On/Off button is present but does nothing.
Leaving sharing, then returning and button is back to off position.

I really dont know if folder sharing is realated, but that is working succesfully through folder properties.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123046/cannot-turn-on-sharing-on-ubuntu-18-04

```
sudo apt install vino
```

Then restart.